# Stopping BitLocker from prompting for the recovery key at startup

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

My motherboard on my laptop was just replaced. I have a hard drive encrypted with BitLocker. How do I get it to stop prompting me for the recovery key at startup?

Extra details:

- I have the recovery key and am able to boot into Windows
- I have initiated the new TPM on the new motherboard
- I have the old owner password file accessible to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable Bitlocker and decrypt your drive. Then, you need need to take ownership of the new TPM and initialize it (this should happen during bitlocker setup). Finally, re-encrypt your drive.

Your drive is encrypted using a key that was stored in your old TPM. That key is not known by your new TPM. Doing this will encrypt your drive with a new key that will be stored in the new TPM, which will cause the prompts to cease.

Answer (score 1):

The method proposed by MDMarra will work, but on a large drive can take Days...  (Just took me 2 days to encrypt a 4TB drive that was 75% full on a Machine with 12 Cores and 24GB of RAM)  you can try to Suspend Protection then Resume...  that reset the drives my system was running bitlocker on, and the message cleared...  and if it works, you will know in Minutes, not days...

Comment: Raw sequential performance on desktop drives tends to be on the order of 100 MB/s. 3 TB at 100 MB/s takes about 30,000 seconds, or 8-9 hours. I/O activity is almost never purely sequential. A day to go through 3 TB of data thus doesn't sound unlikely at all as a first-order estimate.